How Formula can i to move data without Copy and Paste in Excel with criteria list
how can i move data at sheet(database) only select from criteria to the sheet(report)

Here i shared gdrive link for sample link here

I don't see any truck numbers in the database and the only five of the drivers listed on the report sheet seem to match those on the database sheet. Should those five drivers be matched to the trucks (such as AKHMADI matched to truck B 9601 SEI)?

Use and index() with match() based on an ID or shipment number.

Formula for the Shipment Number column:
=IFERROR(INDEX(DATABASE!A$2:A$4796,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(DATABASE!A$2:A$4796)-ROW(DATABASE!A$1))/(DATABASE!D$2:D$4796=1),ROWS(B$4:B4))),"")
Formula for the Act. Time column:
=IF(B4="","",INDEX(DATABASE!C$2:C$4796,MATCH(B4,DATABASE!A$2:A$4796,0)))
